# Problems in suppressing "series" field

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I can't manage to suppress the field "series" with biblatex. I get the error:

```
ERROR: Package keyval Error: series undefined.
```

This is my code:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    series=false,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `series=false` from the options when loading `biblatex` and write this in the preamble:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldset=series, null]
    }
  }
}
```

This suppresses that field for all types of entries.

If you want to remove it only for a particular type of entries, let's say `article`, write

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
       \step[fieldset=series, null]
    }
  }
}
```

instead.

Remark 1. You have to switch to `biber` if you want to be able to use the code. Many `biblatex` features are unsupported if you use `bibtex` as a backend...

Remark 2. The option `<field>=true/false` is available only for the following fields: `isbn`, `url`, `doi`, `eprint`.

### EDIT

As a workaround, when using `bibtex` as a backend, adding the following line to the preamble

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{series}}
```

should be the right trick.