# How can I remove common fields using `biblatex`?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to remove the page numbers, volume numbers, and journal number from my `biblatex` bibliography (for my cv).  I thought I could use `key=false,` like I use for `url` and `doi` but these `pages`, `volume`, and `number` are not valid key values.  I resorted to simply commenting out these lines from the `bib` files as a quick fix but I expected there to be an option within the biblatex package.  How would I do this using option commands?

This is what did not work:

```
\usepackage[
  sorting=none,
  maxnames=99,
  firstinits=true,
  doi=true,
  % pages=false,  % >>> had to comment this out <<<
  % volume=false, % >>> had to comment this out <<<
  % number=false, % >>> had to comment this out <<<
  url=false,
  isbn=false]{biblatex}
```

Comment: See also [Is it possible to suppress a specific field from bibtex .bbl in biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32930/35864), [Excessive fields in biblatex could not be removed if using \fullcite](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229428/35864), [Problems in suppressing “series” field](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128928/35864) as well as *Suppressing of specific BibTeX fields* in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you compile your bibliography with `biber`, simply add

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{pages}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{volume}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: AFAIK `\clearfield` and friends are not specific to Biber, they work with all back-ends. You might want to highlight the difference and use cases of `\clearlist`, `\clearfield` and `\clearname`. Additionally you could mention Biber's source-mapping to clean fields.

Comment: I recall using this previously for removing the notes from a bib file.  Though it does not use `biber` or `biblatex` options, this seems like a better option than manually commenting out each undesired line from the bib file.

Comment: If you go for a more detailed answer, @moewe, I'll gladly remove mine. Or I can transform it as a community wiki, if you prefer.

Comment: Oh no, please don't remove your answer, it is fine as it is. I just wanted to clear up that this can be used without Biber and point out the common mistake to assume that everything can be cleared with `\clearfield`.